# Updating property when promise is resolved

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise

Expected result: data from response is displayed on modal

Actual result: data from response is not displayed on modal

Context: I'm using a form to submit data to a search function with a promise to get results from a db. When I submit, I also open a modal to display the results. The modal already opens with a property called `allResults` that is empty. I'm trying to understand how to bind the data that I get  from the resolved promise to the `allResults` property connected to the modal. Or in other words, how to trigger a property "refresh" when promise gets resolved. When I implement either a `watch` or `computed` property they get called before the data is returned.

Properties:

```
data () {
  return {
    allResults: [],
    query: ''
}}
```

The search function uses graphql apollo:

```
onSubmit () {
  this.$apollo.query({
    query: FIND_PEOPLE,
    variables: {
      name: this.query
    }
  }).then((response) => {
        let a = response.data.given_names  # array
        let b = response.data.family_names # array
        let c = []

        a.forEach(function(el) {
          if (!c.includes(el)) {
            c.push(el)
          }
        })
        var result = c.map(a => a.id);
        b.forEach(function(el) {
          if (!result.includes(el.id)) {
            c.push(el)
          }
        })

        this.allResults.people = []
        this.allResults.people = c
        this.allResults.clubs = response.data.clubs
  });
}
```

The form:

```
<b-nav-form @submit="onSubmit">
  <b-form-input size="sm" class="mr-sm-2" type="text" v-model="query" id="navbar-search-input" />
  <b-button size="sm" class="my-2 my-sm-0" v-b-modal="'search-results-modal'" type="submit">Zoek</b-button>
</b-nav-form>
```

The modal:

```
  <SearchResultsModal :all-results="allResults" :query="query"/>
```

The modal component:

```
<b-modal hide-footer ref="searchResultsModal" id="search-results-modal">
<p>{{"Searchterm: " + this.query}}</p>

<ul v-for="result of this.allResults.people" :key="result.id">
  <li><b-link @click="selectResult('person', result.id)">{{result|personFullName}}</b-link></li>
</ul>
</b-modal>
```

Props:

```
props: ['allResults', 'query'],
```

Additional context:

Please advise

Comment: I think this entirely depends on what `SearchResultsModal` does with its `allResults` prop. Also, should that be `:all-results="allResults"`? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52275413/283366

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the kebab-case improvement. The `SearchResultsModal` displays `allResults` as a list of links.

Comment: So after fixing the attribute (if necessary), it still isn't working? I was actually asking what you did with the `prop` value in the component; how is it assigned or used? Please show some actual code

Comment: Fixing was a style issue, it still works. Added code per your request.

Comment: _"it still works"_ <- I'm confused now... does it work or is it still broken?

Comment: Additional context: When I search the same for the 2nd time, the data is already connected to the property so then "it still works". The first time the data is not showing in the modal, so it does not work as expected.

Comment: `this.allResults.people = []` is totally redundant as you assign `c` on the very next line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a data initialisation and reactivity issue.

You initially set `allResults` to an empty array, cool. But then you appear to be assigning it an object, indicated by your use of `this.allResults.people`.

Vue wasn't aware of the `people` property on `allResults` so it cannot react to it.

Initialise your data so Vue knows about its properties

```
data () {
  return {
    query: '',
    allResults: { // an object, not an array
      people: [],
      clubs: [] // assuming this is also an array
    }
  }
}
```

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: Added information in `.then` of the search function to clarify that I already have this part solved of data initialisation & reactivity.

Comment: @Robert no you don't. You're still initialising `allResults` as an array then adding properties to it and not via `Vue.set`

Comment: @Robert I've update my answer to explain what I've been trying to point out