# Accessing data in created from props Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, prop

I am not able to access data from props in created function.
Its working fine in methods as you can see in below code.

[image]

And its working in methods as you see below

[image]

```js
export default {
    props: ['projectId'],
    data() {
        return {
            elements: []
        }
    },
    created() {
        axios.get(`api/projects/${this.projectId}/elements`).then(response => {
           this.elements = response.data.data
        });
    },
    methods: {
        addingElement(element) {
            alert(this.projectId);
        }
    }
}
```

Parent template

```
<add-project-element :projectId="project.id"></add-project-element>
```

Thanks

Comment: its says undefine in the console log.

Comment: screenshot added

Comment: Cheers. How are you including this component? Where is the code / template from the parent? How are you setting the `projectId` prop?

Comment: Also, looks like your API URL should start with a `/`, ie `/api/projects/${this.projectId}/elements`

Comment: <add-project-element :projectId="project.id"></add-project-element>

Comment: this is how i passed the id

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VueJS Component, can't override class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52275179/vuejs-component-cant-override-class/52275413#52275413)

Answer (score 2):

`<add-project-element :projectId="project.id"></add-project-element>` has to be

```
<add-project-element :project-id="project.id"></add-project-element>
```

HTML attribute names are case-insensitive. Any uppercase character will be interpreted as lowercase. So camelCased prop names need to use their kebab-cased equivalents.

Comment: You are right, but here the ID is coming in props but I am not able to access in created or mounted

Comment: @AmirUrRehman When and how is the `id` property assigned to `project` in the parent scope?

Comment: import AddProjectElement from './AddProjectElements.vue'
components: {
            Datepicker,
            AddProjectElement
        }

<add-project-element :project-id="project.id"></add-project-element>

Comment: imported component, used it, and used the tag

Comment: can you come to private chat, please

Comment: I answered my own question, it worked. please check it @Phil

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your `axios` request. Your prop is `projectId` but you have `project.id` there...

Comment: sorry i updated the question its not working its says undefine

Answer (score 0):

Ok so finally I found something, I am not sure if its right but its working fine.

actually, props are rendering after created that's why its shows undefine. so I set some time. and it worked

```
    created() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        axios.get(`/api/projects/${self.projectId}/elements`)
            .then(response => {
                this.elements = response.data.data
            });
    }, 1)
},
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: If you're having to add a timeout, I suspect your parent component is rendering the `AddProjectElement` component **before** the `project` data is populated. This is why I asked you the question... _"When and how is the `id` property assigned to `project` in the parent scope?"_